# prime faces upload

Tags: file-upload, jsf-2, primefaces

I have problem uploading with primefaces upload widget. After some investigation I noticed that it is sending wrong post type "url-data-encoded" as opposed to multi-patrt request. Even though my form clearly declares it :

```
p:dialog name= "upload" id="mapping" header="Upload Mapping File" widgetVar="mappingFileDialog" fixedCenter="true">
     <h:form prependId="true" id="uploadMapping" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <p:fileUpload value="#{panaceaController.file}" mode="simple"/>
                    <p:commandButton id="uploadbuttom" value="Submit" ajax="true" 
            action="#{panaceaController.handleFileUpload}"/>
     </h:form>
    </p:dialog>
```

What happens is that the file field in the controller is null. 
Other thing that I guess is related is that I have multiple forms in this page, I guess primefaces submits the wrong form.

BTW if I disable ajax for the upload form, the request enctype is correct, but it doesn't invoke the action anymore?!

This is my html form:

```
<h:form prependId="false">
    <p:dataTable id="instances" lazy="false" paginator="false" var="instance"
                 value="#{panaceaController.instances}">
        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Name"/>
            </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{instance.name}"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Directory"/>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{instance.directory}"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                Options
            </f:facet>
            <p:commandLink async="true" update="propertiesTable" oncomplete="propertiesDialog.show();">
                <h:graphicImage value="img/properties.png" />
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{instance}" target="#{panaceaController.instance}"/>
            </p:commandLink>

            <p:commandLink async="true"  onclick="confirmDelete.show();" >
                <h:graphicImage value="img/edit-delete.png"/>
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{instance}" target="#{panaceaController.instance}"/>
            </p:commandLink>
            <p:commandLink async="true"  onclick="mappingFileDialog.show();" >
                <h:graphicImage value="img/mapping.png"/>
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{instance}" target="#{panaceaController.instance}"/>
            </p:commandLink>

        </p:column>

    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
<p:dialog id="properties" header="Properties"  widgetVar="propertiesDialog" fixedCenter="true">
    <h:panelGroup id="propertiesTable" >
        <p>
        Properties for #{panaceaController.instance.directory} :
        </p>
    <h:form>
    <p:dataTable id="propertyTable" var="propertyInstance" value="#{panaceaController.instance.properties}" paginator="false">
        <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{propertyInstance.name}"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <h:inputText value = "#{propertyInstance.value}" required="true"/>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
        <h:commandButton action="#{panaceaController.saveProperties}" value="Save"/>
    </h:form>
    </h:panelGroup>
</p:dialog>
<h:form>
<p:confirmDialog widgetVar="confirmDelete" message="Are you sure you want to delete this Panacea instance?"
                                         severity="warn">
      <p:commandButton value="Yes" update="instances" oncomplete="confirmDelete.hide()"
            actionListener="#{panaceaController.delete}"  />
      <p:commandButton value="Not" onclick="confirmDelete.hide()" type="button"  />
</p:confirmDialog>
</h:form>
<p:dialog name= "upload" id="mapping" header="Upload Mapping File" widgetVar="mappingFileDialog" fixedCenter="true">
 <h:form prependId="true" id="uploadMapping" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <p:fileUpload value="#{panaceaController.file}" mode="simple"/>
                <p:commandButton id="uploadbuttom" value="Submit" ajax="false" async="false"
        action="#{panaceaController.handleFileUpload}"/>
 </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

Comment: The usual primefaces questions here: - do you have the filter set up in the web.xml?  What version? Primefaces is in heavy development and things slip by, but I have not seen the form render improperly for the multipart. If you really need to get dirty, extends the filter, drop a breakpoint in it an examine what's actually going on. My guess is that you're seeing another form on submission.

Comment: Yes,Yes, java code, xhtml code, web.xml code, version...

Comment: primefaces version is 3.0M1. I don't have any filter set up in the web.xml, I didn't see any in primefaces examples either. I will post my xhtml as an answer.

Comment: Here is some progress on this: If I disable ajax, it actually submits the form correctly and send the attached file, except it doesn't invoke my action now. I tried action and actionListener, none of them worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I don't have any filter set up in the web.xml*

You need to configure the PrimeFaces file upload filter in `web.xml` as per the [PrimeFaces User Guide](http://primefaces.org/documentation.html). Here's an extract of page 170 of the User Guide for [3.0.M4](http://primefaces.googlecode.com/files/primefaces_users_guide_3M4.pdf):

> ## 3.34 FileUpload
>
> ...
>
> #### Getting started with FileUpload
>
> First thing to do is to configure the fileupload filter which parses the multipart request. FileUpload filter should map to Faces Servlet.
>
> ```
> <filter>
>     <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
>     <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
> </filter>
> <filter-mapping>
>     <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
>     <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
> </filter-mapping>
> ```

The same applies as good for older beta versions like M1 as you have.